# Base64 encoding from a website and terminal give two different results

Tags: base64

I used following command on terminal

```
`echo admin:admin | base64`
```

It gives me following output

```
YWRtaW46YWRtaW4K
```

But when I used https://www.base64encode.org/ for the same string `admin:admin` it gives me following

```
YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

The reason this behaviour is the new line added by the `echo` command. Normally the `echo` command add a new line at the end which leads to a different encoding. Therefore if you use it with `echo -n admin:admin | base64` the difference won't occur.

Comment: Apparently, `base64 <<< "$VALUE"` also adds a newline.

Comment: also surround your parameter with single quotes, makes difference with symbols like &:
```echo -n 'admin:adm&n' | base64```